# Orthogonal Geodesics to Solar Eclipse Geopath

Tags: geographics, geodesy

I'm trying to find the perpendicular geodesics to the path the upcoming solar eclipse will take:

Path:

```
gpath  = SolarEclipse[ "TotalPhaseCenterLine", EclipseType -> "Total"];

GeoGraphics[gpath, GeoRange -> {{24, 50}, {-128, -63}}]
```

[image: Solar Path]

What I would like are perpendicular lines similar to this image:

[image: eclipse]

source: https://www.greatamericaneclipse.com/nation/

So far I can create path offsets relative to the pole:

```
GeoGraphics[{
    Red, 
    GeoMarker[GeoPosition@#, "Scale" -> Offset[10]],
    Green,
    GeoPath[{GeoPosition@#, GeoDisplacement[{Quantity[1000, "Miles"], 180}]}]
} & /@ gpath[[1]], GeoRange -> {{24, 50}, {-128, -63}}]
```

[image: Pole lines]

Any ideas how I can make the lines orthogonal for the full length of the eclipse path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the points of the geo path, and thread the GeoPosition head to have a list of individual geo positions:

```
points = Thread[gpath[[1]]];
```

Take them in pairs and compute the direction from the first to the second point in each pair, and add 90 degrees to get the perpendicular (use -90 for the north-pointing geodesics):

```
directions = GeoDirection @@@ Subsequences[points, {2}] + Quantity[90, "AngularDegrees"];
```

These are approximate perpendicular geodesics at those points (I'm not sure those are the green lines in the other map you show):

```
geopaths = MapThread[GeoPath[{#1, Quantity[1000, "Kilometers"], #2}] &, {Most[points], directions}];
```

Now you can plot everything together:

```
GeoGraphics[{gpath, Green, geopaths}, GeoRange -> {{24, 50}, {-128, -63}}]
```

[image]